# Is the article an correctly used here

Tags: articles

Here is the first sentence from an economic article:

"According to STATS’s preliminary estimates, broadly in line with
expectations, GDP has fallen by 12.1% YoY in February 2021, following **an**
11% YoY drop in January 2021."

Is article "an" in bold face in the above sentence correct? Should not it be "the" instead? since the 11% is specific not general. It is that 11% of january which we know.

If "an" is correct then what is the rational for it?

Comment: [Is the article an correctly used here?] What is STATS's?

Comment: "An 11% drop" = "a drop of 11%". (_An_ is used because _eleven_ begins with a vowel.)

Comment: Either is fine. 'The 11% drop ... in 2021' refers to the specific drop while 'an 11% drop ... in 2021'  is shorthand for something like 'there was a drop ... in 2021 of 11%'.

Comment: @Lambie STAT's in the name of an organization. Thanks for correcting my title. :)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Thanks. Since this article is talking about the specific data of the specific country should not it be unanimously "the"?

Comment: @Lambie There is no such thing in my native language as article. Hence, it is very unfamiliar to me naturally. I learned some rules in my high school when I was learning English but since then I have never really paid attention to articles. I have developed some gut feeeling where to use which. But lately, I found particular interest and would like to find out their logic. So, would be nice if you could pass a helping hand wihtout judgement. :)

Comment: He just answered your question, so why are you asking it again? Read his answer, and look at the two sentences I gave you. It is always the same thing. "the" is specific, "a" is not.

Comment: I am not passing judgment, I know that Russian and some other Slavic languages do not have articles. Also, you might go and do some search on the ELL site. There are tons of questions and answers about a/the.

Comment: What Kate said: An is used because eleven begins with a vowel. An 8%, a 9%, a 10%, an 11%, etc. It has nothing to do with "an" versus "the."

Comment: @MarkHubbard That is very clear. So, you go for indefinite article, right?

Comment: Yes, I do. To my ear, "an 11% drop" is "smoother" and more natural than "the 11% drop" in this sentence. However, "the" still would be acceptable usage.

Comment: You would use the definite article if the text had previously mentioned several different changes in GDP (or the reader is presumed to know about them), and you want to single out this one. You use the indefinite article if you're introducing it for the first time here.